# How to get the jQuery MaskedInput unmask() function to work properly?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, maskedtextbox, data-masking

I am trying to have one input on my page that I would like to have a U.S. phone number mask by default. If a end user clicks a checkbox specifing they would like to enter a International phone number I want the mask to be removed.

I have tried multiple ways and have been unsuccessful thus far. In the current project I am using jQuery to hide/show a completely different input. But I don't like that option and would like a more streamlined approach.

I am using the following:

jQuery 1.4.1 (going to upgrade to 1.4.2 soon) and jQuery.MaskedInput-1.2.2

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function($) {
  if ($("#InternationalOfficePhone").attr('checked') == false) {
    $("#OfficePhone").mask("(999) 999-9999? x99999");
  }
});

$("#InternationalOfficePhone").click(function() {
  if ($("#InternationalOfficePhone").attr('checked') == true) {
    //$("#OfficePhone").mask(); //doesn't work
    //$("#OfficePhone").unmask(); //doesn't work
    $("#OfficePhone").unmask("(999) 999-9999? x99999"); //doesn't work
  } else {
    $("#OfficePhone").mask("(999) 999-9999? x99999");
  }
});
</script>
```

The code above works properly to set the default mask, but no matter what I try on the click event for the InternationalOfficePhone it doesn't remove the mask.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: The error I am getting is on the un/mask lines and it returns an "Object doesn't support this property or method"

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I was able to figure out the code to get it to work. Below is the code I am using now.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function($) {
  $("#OfficePhone").mask("(999) 999-9999? x99999");
  $("#InternationalOfficePhone").click(function() {
    var mask = "(999) 999-9999? x99999";
    if ($("#InternationalOfficePhone").is(':checked')) {
      $("#OfficePhone").unmask(mask);
    } else {
      $("#OfficePhone").mask(mask);
    }
  });
});
</script>
```

Comment: `.unmask()` works perfectly. All I needed, thanks. But as pointed out in Diego's answer, you do not need to pass a parameter to the function.

Comment: Does this still work with maskedInput 1.4.1?  I'm finding that neither `.unmask()` nor `.unmask(maskString)` removes the functionality from the field nor the mask-inserted characters from the value.  I had to call `.mask()` again (no arguments) to get the unmasked value, as suggested by [this answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45075512/1279516)

Answer (score 30):

You don't need to pass a parameter to the `unmask` function! 
Use it without a parameter and it works well.

```
$("#OfficePhone").unmask();
```

Comment: Confirmed! Works without parameter. This should probably have been a comment though...

Comment: Why a comment if this is the answer to the question?

Comment: There was already an answered that used the `unmask` function, and your answer reads as if it is building upon that answer

Comment: off course not, the accepted answer is wrong. Terry use .unmask(parameter) and the right answer is .unmask(). This is why I put as a new answer, that time I couldn't edit others.

Comment: Accepted answer is not wrong, but the parameter is not necessary. It still works with the parameter. But I did upvote your answer because it is more correct, given this.

Answer (score 3):

I run through the same problem, and what helped me is:

```
    var maskedInput = $("#id").data('mask');
    if (maskedInput) {
        maskedInput.remove();
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Remove the inputmask:

```
$(selector).inputmask('remove');
```

or

```
var input = document.getElementById(selector);
if (input.inputmask)
  input.inputmask.remove()
```

or

```
Inputmask.remove(document.getElementById(selector));
```

Comment: After $(selector).mask(...)
$(selector).inputmask is undefined.

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: Inputmask is not defined

Comment: @Crimean.us inputmask library must be loaded.
https://github.com/RobinHerbots/Inputmask

Comment: Thank you @EngineerCoder

Comment: Question is related to jquery.maskedinput (https://github.com/digitalBush/jquery.maskedinput) plugin, not to Inputmask (https://github.com/RobinHerbots/Inputmask).

Answer (score 3):

I'm using [jQuery Mask Plugin v1.14.12](https://github.com/igorescobar/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/blob/1526015318a7d6f852ff4aecfec21cb220b6c206/dist/jquery.mask.min.js)

In my case, the `.unmask()` wasn't working because I was using a different selector than the one used when the mask was first created.

For example, let's say this was the input:

```
<input type="text" class="someclass maskme" value="" name="somename" />
```

the mask was created like this:

```
$('.maskme').mask('0000');
```

then, I was trying to unmask it as follows, which wasn't working:

```
$('.someclass').unmask();
```

once I changed it to the following, it worked as expected:

```
$('.maskme').unmask();
```

Answer (score 2):

Try using the `:checked` instead of `attr` check, I think that is the problem. I mean use `$('#InternationalOfficePhone').is(':checked')` in the if condition.

Comment: That didn't make a difference. I am still getting an error on the $("#OfficePhone").unmask() code.

Comment: What is the error you are getting? Check `isMasked` before doing the unmask

Comment: See my posted answer. I was able to finally figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

I am using [query.maskedinput.js Version: 1.4.1](https://github.com/digitalBush/jquery.maskedinput/blob/bb66bf9b1c3eddd1d2349cee103127ae08d0a877/demo/index.html)

the unmasking is done by

```
$("input").blur(function() {
    $("#info").html("Unmasked value: " + $(this).mask());
});
```

example Masking is

```
$("#pannumber").mask("aaaaa 9999 a");
```

Unmasking

```
$("#pannumber").blur(function() { 
    var pannumber=  $(this).mask() ;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using inputmask js Version: 5.0.2.

& am using below techniques for masking and unmasking

```
$("#mailPhone").mask('(999) 999-9999'); //masking.
```

Or

```
$('#mailPhone').inputmask('(999) 999-9999') //masking.
```

&

```
$('#mailPhone').inputmask("remove");  //unmasking.
```