# How to change Phone number format in input as you type?

Tags: jquery, input, formatting, phone-number, maskedinput

**My CodePen:** http://codepen.io/leongaban/pen/cyaAL

I have an input field for a phone number which allows up to 20 characters (for international numbers).

I'm also using the [Masked input jQuery plugin](http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/) by [Josh Bush](https://twitter.com/digitalBush) to format the phone number in the input to make it 'pretty'.

[image]

- My problem is that in the requirements when the phone is 10 digits or
  less, it should use the Masked input formatting.
- However when the phone number is longer then 10 digits, the
  formatting should be removed.

---

Here is my current: [**CodePen**](http://codepen.io/leongaban/pen/cyaAL), Cell Phone is the input field where I'm trying to accomplish this. Work Phone is an example of the default functionality of the [Mask input plugin](http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/).

**How would you go about this problem?**

*jQuery for Cell Phone input field:*

```
case '2':
    console.log('created phone input');
    $('.new_option').append(myphone);
    $('.added_mobilephone').mask('(999) 999-9999? 9');
    $('.added_mobilephone').keypress(function(event){

      if (this.value.trim().length > 10) {
        console.log('this.value = '+this.value.trim());
        console.log('greater then 10');
        $('.added_mobilephone').mask('99999999999999999999');
      }

      /*if (this.value.length < 9) {
        console.log(this.value);
        console.log('less then 10');
        $('.added_mobilephone').mask('(999) 999-9999? 9999999999');
      } else if (this.value.length > 9) {
        console.log(this.value);
        console.log('greater then 10');
        $('.added_mobilephone').mask('99999999999999999999');
      }*/
    });
    break;
```

Comment: Have you checked out this question yet? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2580550/how-to-get-the-jquery-maskedinput-unmask-function-to-work-properly
That question's method of checking a box indicating international # or not could be good from a user-experience standpoint as well (in your current version, int'l users may get confused when initially presented with the default US phone format)

Comment: Oh sweet thanks for the link! Checking it out now, will see if I can get it to work better

Comment: Thank you. I was able to get this plugin working for my form input :)

Comment: $("#pr_phone").inputmask("+9 999 999 9999", { onKeyValidation: function (key, result) { } }); I have added it like this example. But i want to set '+1' fixed for country code so that no one can change it. Please suggest. Thanks.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You've probably already solved this problem, but it's worth noting for future reference that anyone else with the need to apply multiple masks to a control may want to explore this [inputmask plugin](https://github.com/RobinHerbots/jquery.inputmask/tree/2.x/js).

It has more callbacks, settings and many out of the box mask types(be sure to take a look at the extension files).  You can also define multiple masks for a control, and the plugin will try and apply the appropriate mask based on the value.

[Here is a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ePDq7/) to demo the previous statement:

```js
$(window).load(function()
{
   var phones = [{ "mask": "(###) ###-####"}, { "mask": "(###) ###-##############"}];
    $('#textbox').inputmask({ 
        mask: phones, 
        greedy: false, 
        definitions: { '#': { validator: "[0-9]", cardinality: 1}} });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.inputmask/3.1.62/jquery.inputmask.bundle.js"></script>
<input type='text' id='textbox' />
```

Comment: do I have to add the whole paste you shared through jsfiddle ?

Comment: @KhanShahrukh That's one way of doing it.  I just updated the answer with a snippet that includes a CDN for inputmask.  You should have everything you need in that bundle.

Comment: I'm aware of the outdatedness of this answer. @Roop Kumar has given a much better answer below.

Comment: The OP asked how to do this in a very specific library.  The library I recommended is a branch of what he's using.  If all you need to do is simply format text then RoopKumars answer is better suited.  The plugin being used is heavier, but does much more than format text.  It's pretty great, one of my favorites.  I'd still recommend it if you're able to use it.

Comment: $("#pr_phone").inputmask("+9 999 999 9999", { onKeyValidation: function (key, result) { } }); I have added it like this example. But i want to set '+1' fixed for country code so that no one can change it. Please suggest. Thanks.

Answer (score 45):

```
$("input[name='phone']").keyup(function() {
    $(this).val($(this).val().replace(/^(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d+)$/, "($1)$2-$3"));
});
```

This will work for sure and will properly handle populating the full string at once (e.g., 1234567890).

```js
/* example jquery use */

$("input[name='phone']").keyup(function() {
    $(this).val($(this).val().replace(/^(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d+)$/, "($1)$2-$3"));
});
```

```css
/* use your css to beautify the form */
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- form input for example user -->
<form>
  <input type="text" name="phone" placeholder="Phone Number" />
</form>
```

Comment: I wish I could upvote this 100 times. Best solution.

Answer (score 24):

This was very helpful, I only add some code to make it works when user delete some characters, I gave the option of entering only numbers and a max length. This works for me :)

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  /***phone number format***/
  $(".phone-format").keypress(function (e) {
    if (e.which != 8 && e.which != 0 && (e.which < 48 || e.which > 57)) {
      return false;
    }
    var curchr = this.value.length;
    var curval = $(this).val();
    if (curchr == 3 && curval.indexOf("(") <= -1) {
      $(this).val("(" + curval + ")" + "-");
    } else if (curchr == 4 && curval.indexOf("(") > -1) {
      $(this).val(curval + ")-");
    } else if (curchr == 5 && curval.indexOf(")") > -1) {
      $(this).val(curval + "-");
    } else if (curchr == 9) {
      $(this).val(curval + "-");
      $(this).attr('maxlength', '14');
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="phone-format"  type="text" placeholder="Phone Number">
```

Comment: This should be the best answer.

Comment: Bundle of Thanks. Rivers

Comment: This does not work well when trying to erase what you have written!

Comment: @Leti Thank you very much.

Comment: @BernieCarpio Thank you very much

Comment: Perfect solution. Should be at the top.

Comment: Awesome answer, for format 555-555-5555 I adapted to this: $(".phone-format").keypress(function (e) {
        if (e.which != 8 && e.which != 0 && (e.which < 48 || e.which > 57)) {
          return false;
        }
        var curchr = this.value.length;
        var curval = $(this).val();
        if (curchr == 3 && curval.indexOf("-") <= -1) {
          $(this).val(curval + "-");
        } else if (curchr == 7) {
          $(this).val(curval + "-");
          $(this).attr('maxlength', '12');
        }
      });

Comment: Thank You very much Sir

Comment: Thank you so much, this should be the top answer

Answer (score 8):

In your case

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jasny-bootstrap/3.1.3/js/jasny-bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" class="form-control" data-mask="(999) 999-9999">
```

with [jasny bootstrap](http://www.jasny.net/bootstrap/2.3.1/javascript.html#inputmask) plugin

Comment: ah! made my life a tiny bit easy. worked like a charm

Answer (score 4):

I tried some of the non-plugin answers but they unfortunately had undesirable side effects when editing the phone number.  Here is a solution that I ended up creating that is simple and has no special external 3rd party lib dependency:

- Does not require any plugins --> just JS and JQuery
- Filters out non-digits (i.e. noise) automatically
- Shifts left the phone number digits on deletion of digits
- Maintains format / does not break down on deletion
- Does nothing if nothing changes e.g. allows cursor to move left/right to make change vs. other solutions which kept cursor pegged to end

CAVEAT: The phone number considered is only North America which was fine in my case as this was used for local community soccer registration in Canada.

```
$("input[name='phone_num']").keyup(function() {
  var val_old = $(this).val();
  var val = val_old.replace(/\D/g, '');
  var len = val.length;
  if (len >= 1)
    val = '(' + val.substring(0);
  if (len >= 3)
    val = val.substring(0, 4) + ') ' + val.substring(4);
  if (len >= 6)
    val = val.substring(0, 9) + '-' + val.substring(9);
  if (val != val_old)
    $(this).focus().val('').val(val);
});
```

Comment: I wish I could upvote this 1,000 times. Thanks @nikolaosinlight this is flawless.

Answer (score 4):

Input type text to input type telephone number. max-length, placeholder using jquery.

```js
// Used to format phone number and add placeholder and max-length
function phoneFormatter() {
 $(' input[type="text"]').attr({ placeholder : '(___) ___-____' });
  $('input[tabindex="111"]').on('input', function() {
    var number = $(this).val().replace(/[^\d]/g, '')
    if (number.length == 7) {
      number = number.replace(/(\d{3})(\d{4})/, "$1-$2");
    } else if (number.length == 10) {
      number = number.replace(/(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{4})/, "($1) $2-$3");
     
    }
    $(this).val(number)
    $('input[type="text"]').attr({ maxLength : 10 });
    
  });
};

$(phoneFormatter);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="input_111[]" value="" tabindex="111">
```

Comment: Above jQuery Easily maintain in page

Comment: Perfect! this is it, what I was looking for. 

Answer (score 2):

Check the below answer out.
 
I created for the TSP code(One of my project) but the similar structure works for the Phone number. Solution is fairly simple. 
I am using the KeyCode to the below solution. More information about the keycode could be found [here](https://www.cambiaresearch.com/articles/15/javascript-char-codes-key-codes).

```
 $(function () {
    $('#txtphonenumber').keydown(function (e) {
    var key = e.charCode || e.keyCode || 0;
    $text = $(this); 
       if (key !== 8 && key !== 9) {
          if ($text.val().length === 3) {
             $text.val($text.val() + '-');
          }
          if ($text.val().length === 7) {
             $text.val($text.val() + '-');
          }
       }
       return ((key >= 48 && key <= 57) || (key >= 96 && key <= 105) || key == 46 || key == 8 || key == 9 );
      // KeyCode from 48 to 57 are the Numeric characters
      // KeyCode from 96 to 105 are the numpad 0 to numpad 9
      // KeyCode delete 46
      // KeyCode backspace 8
      // KeyCode tab 9
  })
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is my solution (for US numbers) that works as you type

```
const maskPhoneNumber = (s) => {
  let o = '';
  o += s.length >= 3 ? `(${s.substring(0, 3)}` : s;
  o += s.length >= 4 ? `) ${s.substring(3, 6)}` : s.substring(3);
  o += s.length >= 7 ? `-${s.substring(6)}` : '';
  return o;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Similar solution above but in this script the format is applying meanwhile the user is typing.
Adding mask in the phone number - Brazilian Phone Format (00) ?0000-0000.
It can be helpful for others as well.

```js
    //Add mask (00) ?0000-0000 in the phone number - Brazil Format
    $('#iTel').on("keyup blur", function(e){
     var v = $(this).val();
     v = v.replace(/[^\d]/g,'');
     if(v.length < 6){
      v = v.replace(/(\d{2})/, '($1) ');
     }else if(v.length < 10){
      v = v.replace(/(\d{2})(\d{4})/, '($1) $2-');
     }else if(v.length < 11){
      v = v.replace(/(\d{2})(\d{4})(\d{4})/, '($1) $2-$3');    
     }else {
      v = v.replace(/(\d{2})(\d{5})(\d{4})/, '($1) $2-$3');
     }
    $(this).val(v);  
       });
```

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
     <html lang="en">
     <head>
       <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <form method="post" id="cadForm" action="incluir.php">
    <div class="form-row">
     <div class="form-group col-md-12">
     <label for="iTel" class="col-form-label">Phone</label>
     <div class="input-group">
     <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-phone" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
     <input type="text" class="form-control" name="iTel" id="iTel" maxlength="15" placeholder="(xx) ?xxxx-xxxx..." pattern="[(][0-9]{2}[)][\s][0-9]{4,5}[-][0-9]{4}$" title="Please, type only number: (00) ?0000-0000">
     </div>   
    </div>
      </body>
     </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

extension to [Roop Kumar](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37066380/696358) answer if one only wants to keep digits

than add **replace(/\D/g,'')**

```
$(this).val($(this).val().replace(/\D/g,'').replace(/^(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d+)$/, "($1)$2-$3"));
```

Hopes that helps